# How to be a member of pulseaudio gitlab?

Tags: gitlab, open-source, pulseaudio

I made an issue in https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pulseaudio/pulseaudio/-/issues/3801
And I tried to make a commit to try to fix

But when I try push my commit on puleaudio repository, it is blocked because of permission

And I found that there is a way to request to merge my commit by "Merge Request" menu in https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pulseaudio/pulseaudio

But I have no menu for "Merge Request"

I think there is a process to be a member to enable "Merge Request" menu to contribute the source

Is there anyone who can guide to me for this process?

I tried to find out the way to be a member in google
But still I could not the way